# Given checkpoint files, how do I generate the output node name of my model

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working with checkpoint files and a model with output/tensors that weren't explicitly named.

I understand how naming works:

[Tensorflow: What is the output node name in Cifar-10 model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906093/tensorflow-what-is-the-output-node-name-in-cifar-10-model) && [How does TensorFlow name tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors)

But I am unsure of how to generate the names from existing checkpoint files (no pb's were generated and I need this in order to get that):

```
model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt.index
model.ckpt.meta
```

The CNN in question is [fast-neural-style](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer)

Answer (score 2):

From [KeyError : The tensor variable , Refer to the tensor which does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166819/keyerror-the-tensor-variable-refer-to-the-tensor-which-does-not-exists)

This prints out all tensor names and you can try and figure out which one you need.

```
model_path = "my_model.ckpt"

sess = tf.Session()

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + ".meta")
saver.restore(sess, model_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

for op in graph.get_operations():
    print(op.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

So with that current model, I found that in `evaluate.py` you can access the restored graph and simply print to find out the name.

```
with g.as_default(), g.device(device_t), \
            tf.Session(config=soft_config) as sess:
        batch_shape = (batch_size,) + img_shape
        img_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=batch_shape,
                                         name='img_placeholder')

        preds = transform.net(img_placeholder)
        print(preds)
```

output:

`Tensor("add_37:0", shape=(1, 720, 884, 3), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)`

In this case the operation was add, and tensorflow named it accordingly: **add_37**