# KeyError : The tensor variable , Refer to the tensor which does not exists

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

Using **LSTMCell** i  trained a model to do text generation . I started the tensorflow session and save all the tensorflow varibles using **tf.global_variables_initializer()** .

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
//code blocks
run_init_op = tf.global_variables_intializer()
sess.run(run_init_op)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
#varible that makes prediction
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last,weight)+bias)
#feed the inputdata into model and trained
#saved the model
#save the tensorflow model
save_path= saver.save(sess,'/tmp/text_generate_trained_model.ckpt')
print("Model saved in the path : {}".format(save_path))
```

The model get trained and saved all its session . Link to review the whole code  [lstm_rnn.py](https://github.com/Madhivarman/DR/blob/master/neuralnetwork/lstm_rnn.py)

Now i loaded the stored model and tried to do text generation for the document . So,i restored the model with following code

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
imported_data = tf.train.import_meta_graph('text_generate_trained_model.ckpt.meta')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    imported_meta.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

    #accessing the default graph which we restored
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    #op that we can be processed to get the output
    #last is the tensor that is the prediction of the network
    y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")
    #generate characters
    for i in range(500):
        x = np.reshape(pattern,(1,len(pattern),1))
        x = x / float(n_vocab)
        prediction = sess.run(y_pred,feed_dict=x)
        index = np.argmax(prediction)
        result = int_to_char[index]
        seq_in = [int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]
        sys.stdout.write(result)
        patter.append(index)
        pattern = pattern[1:len(pattern)]

    print("\n Done...!")
sess.close()
```

I came to know that the prediction variable does not exist in the graph.

> KeyError: "The name 'prediction:0' refers to a Tensor which does not
>   exist. The operation, 'prediction', does not exist in the graph."

Full code is available here [text_generation.py](https://github.com/Madhivarman/DR/blob/master/neuralnetwork/text_generation.py)

Though i saved all tensorflow varibles , the prediction tensor is not saved in the tensorflow computation graph . whats wrong in my **lstm_rnn.py** file .

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction:0")` to work you should have named it when you created it. This is how you can name it

```
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last,weight)+bias, name="prediction")
```

If you have already trained the model and can't rename the tensor, you can still get that tensor by its default name as in,

```
y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Reshape_1:0")
```

If `Reshape_1` is not the actual name of the tensor, you'll have to look at the names in the graph and figure it out.
You can inspect that with

```
for op in graph.get_operations():
    print(op.name)
```

Comment: I have similar problem, but when I use your suggestion and name my layer as `prediction = tf.layers.dense(net, 8, name='prediction_output')` I get operations named like `prediction_output/bias
prediction_output/bias/read
prediction_output/bias/Initializer/zeros
prediction_output/bias/Assign
prediction_output/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer/scale
` but not any name `prediction_output`, which is why I get the error `KeyError: "The name 'prediction_output:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'prediction_output', does not exist in the graph."
` How can I resolve this?

Comment: The layer in my answer is `tf.nn.softmax` which doesn't have parameters like bias or weights. On the other hand you are using `tf.layers.dense` which has those parameters, hence you'll have the bias and weights named after the name you assign to the layer. If you want your output in `prediction_output`, you can leave the dense layer unnamed, and then pass its output to an identity function with that name.
`prediction = tf.layers.dense(net, 8)
final_output = tf.identity(prediction, name='prediction_output')`