# The name 'image_tensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'image_tensor', does not exist in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with a teammate to create an image classification and localization system. We are using Tensorflow 2 and python 3. We know that we are using some deprecated functions that are part of Tensorflow 1 though.
I trained a model in tensorflow and exported it as a frozen_inference_graph.pb
My teammate used a prebuilt frozen inference graph, found here as Faster-RCNN Inception v2: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#use-existing-config-file-for-your-model

When he runs his code normally, it runs fine, but when we replace the prebuilt frozen inference graph with my frozen inference graph we get the error:
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'image_tensor:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'image_tensor', does not exist in the graph.

We believe that the inference graph that my teammate used contained an input tensor named "image_tensor" and in my model we have no input tensors. Is this an accurate assessment? If his model used this input tensor and mine didn't, then is there a work around, or will I have to remake my model?

Has anyone had this problem, or at least could point me in a direction? I've looked at similar questions and nothing has helped.

Code for my model is:

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL 
from PIL import Image

print(tf.__version__)
img_height = 28
img_width = 28

model = keras.Sequential([
    #complex
    layers.Input((28,28,1)), #28 * 28 pixels, only 1 color (greyscale)
    #layers.LayerNormalization(axis=1),
    layers.Dense(256, activation="selu"), #256 nodes,  activation = rectify linear unit, fast activation function
    layers.Dense(128, activation="selu"),
    layers.Conv2D(128,3, padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    layers.Dense(64, activation="selu"),
    layers.Dense(32, activation="selu"),
    layers.Conv2D(32,3, padding='same'), #2d convulution layer
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),#downsamples input so that feature maps can be created. usually added after convulution layer
    layers.Flatten(), #[[1],[2],[3]] --> [1,2,3]
    layers.Dense(3), #representing 3 classes, output layer
    layers.Activation('softmax')
    #simple
    #layers.Input((28,28,1)),
    #layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 3)), 
    #layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    #layers.Dropout(0.3),
    #layers.Dense(3),
])
model.summary()

    #SPLITTING DATA
#Train file contains ALL pictures, at random move 50% to the Validation file
import os
import shutil

#Moving I
source = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Train/I"
destination = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Validation/I"
files = os.listdir(source)
for f in files:
    if np.random.rand(1) < 0.5:
        shutil.move(source + '/'+ f, destination + '/'+ f)

#moving L
source = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Train/L"
destination = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Validation/L"
files = os.listdir(source)
for f in files:
    if np.random.rand(1) < 0.5:
        shutil.move(source + '/'+ f, destination + '/'+ f)
        
#moving T
source = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Train/T"
destination = "C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Validation/T"
files = os.listdir(source)
for f in files:
    if np.random.rand(1) < 0.5:
        shutil.move(source + '/'+ f, destination + '/'+ f)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


ds_train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Train',
        target_size=(28, 28),
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True,
        seed=1953)


ds_validation = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/evanp/AI/Capstone/Demo_images/Validation',
        target_size=(28, 28),
        color_mode='grayscale',
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True,
        seed=1953)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss=[
        keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    ],
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=ds_train.n//ds_train.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=ds_validation.n//ds_validation.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=ds_train,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=ds_validation,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=10
                   )
```

The code that my teammate is using is as follows, and the only thing that we change is

PATH_TO_CKPT = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

becomes

PATH_TO_CKPT = "MY_frozen_inference_graph.pb"

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 848, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

print("Starting streaming")
pipeline.start(config)

# load tensorflow
print("[INFO] Loading model...")
PATH_TO_CKPT = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
print("[INFO] Model loaded.")
colors_hash = {}
while True:
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
    depth = frames.get_depth_frame()




    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    scaled_size = (color_frame.width, color_frame.height)
    # expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(color_image, axis=0)
    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                                                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
    scores = np.squeeze(scores)

    for idx in range(int(num)):
        class_ = classes[idx]
        score = scores[idx]
        box = boxes[idx]
        
        if class_ not in colors_hash:
            colors_hash[class_] = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))
        
        if score > 0.6:
            left = int(box[1] * color_frame.width)
            top = int(box[0] * color_frame.height)
            right = int(box[3] * color_frame.width)
            bottom = int(box[2] * color_frame.height)
            
            p1 = (left, top)
            p2 = (right, bottom)
            # draw box
            r, g, b = colors_hash[class_]
            cv2.rectangle(color_image, p1, p2, (int(r), int(g), int(b)), 2, 1)

    cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow('RealSense', color_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

print("[INFO] stop streaming ...")
pipeline.stop()
```

Edit:
I tried the solution here and it didn't work
[KeyError : The tensor variable , Refer to the tensor which does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166819/keyerror-the-tensor-variable-refer-to-the-tensor-which-does-not-exists)